# How would I create an alias to run a game? (Minecraft)

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I would like to create a command-line alias to run a game (Minecraft in particular).  How would I accomplish this?  I want to type in `runmc` to run the command `java -jar /root/.minecraft/launcher.jar`.  I already put the following into my `.bashrc` file

```
alias runmc="java -jar /root/.minecraft/launcher.jar"
```

It won't detect this as a command.  When I type in `runmc`, it tells me `runmc: command not found`.  How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you actually have a space before the equal sign?

Comment: The asker stated in an answer that is about to be deleted: "NOTE: I didn't ever have a space before the equal sign. That was just a typo."

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code is not working is because you have got an extra space in the wrong place, try changing your code to this, saving, and then launching a new Terminal session and trying again:

```
alias runmc="java -jar /root/.minecraft/launcher.jar"
```

Although it is recommended that instead of declaring aliases in the `.bashrc` file that you instead create them in a file called `.bash_aliases`, if this file does not already exist you should then create it in your home directory where `.bashrc` is located.

And to make sure that the aliases which you put into the `.bash_aliases` file are actually picked up by the system, make sure that this code is not commented out in the `.bashrc` file:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: @Hellolinux: Don't thank me! **;-)** If this answer solved your problem just click the little grey ☑ under the "1" now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"!

Answer (score 0):

Your alias wasn't working because it wasn't *sourced* and this is a [frequent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in), having been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548093/my-bash-aliases-dont-work).

As you have noted it was only the text of your question that had the extra  typo and not the alias you had placed in your `.bashrc`, but your modification needed to be *re-read* for the interactive terminal.

Placing an alias in `.bashrc`  with the "standard" aliases (e.g., `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`) is fine.  The *prefered* location, however, is `.bash_aliases`   This is used by default in nearly all *buntus.

I use a little alias to help me write aliases so I don't forget to *source* them, or need to close my terminals.

Create, or append to your `~/.bash_aliases` file the following

```
###### ea - alias for editing aliases
#
#This alias makes editing alias a
#bit easier and they are useful right away. Note if the source failed, it will not echo "aliases sourced  --ok".
#
#Subsitute medit or your favorite editor, or alter for ksh, sh, etc.
#
alias ea='gedit ~/.bash_aliases; source ~/.bash_aliases && source $HOME/.bash_aliases && echo "aliases sourced  --ok."'
#
```

This alias `ea` makes writing other aliases a snap.

Enter ea and a text editor opens `.bash_aliases`. Add and save your alias(es) and when the text editor is closed your `.bash_aliases` is then *sourced* meaning it is available immediately.  There will also be a `echo` confirmation that all is ok. So when you create your `alias runmc="java -jar /root/.minecraft/launcher.jar"` the whole process is easier, as well as the *next* time you create an alias.